# Button as a fake link for a Google Analytics funnel

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-analytics, traffic

I'm trying to set up a funnel that has a final step of clicking on a button and downloading a document. Since I can't track the button, I was hoping to set up a fake link that doesn't redirect the user anywhere but allows Google Analytics to see how many people clicked on the button.

What I have is this Javascript piece of code but when it gives me an error:

```
<a href=”/goal/example” onclick=”javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview (‘example’);”target=”blank”>
```

Or, if this doesn't work at all, is there any other way to add a button to my funnel?

Thanks!

Comment: What error? "It gives me an error" is like giving a cat a bowl without food: you know something great's there, but it's being withheld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To piggy-back on @nyuen's answer, (though without your error message it's hard to know *what's* wrong), it looks like your link could be improved as well. First, since it sounds like you'd rather it not link anywhere, I'd set the href to your code rather than the onclick. And second, if you don't want it leading anywhere a `target="blank"` is going to be annoying. (Also I assume your `<a>` is closed eventually). Try:

```
<a href="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'example'])">[...]</a>
```

Comment: I'm assuming I should put the button between the <a> but what url would I put in my GA funnel with this method? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe the second argument is actually an identifier, not a URL (it just tends to correspond for convenience), so you should be able to place whatever you'd like the action to be named. Just make sure it begins with a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things wrong with the code looks like. Try this:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'example'])"
```

The `javascript` part is optional, and also the quotes need to be straight quotes, not the 'smart' quotes.